# Dialog in list view Android

Tags: android, listview, android-alertdialog

I have a `listview` which contains elements, and a button delete, when I click on this button I want to display a `dialog` then confirm or not the deleting of the element, the problem is that I can't display the dialog on the `listview`, I have an issue with the context.

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    if(v.getId()==R.id.Supprimer){
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new 
        AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());

        builder.setCancelable(true);
        builder.setTitle("Suppression d'un rendez-vous");
        builder.setMessage("Voulez vous supprimer ce rendez-vous");

        builder.setNegativeButton("Non", new 
        DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                dialogInterface.cancel();
            }
        });

        builder.setPositiveButton("Oui", new 
        DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                //alertTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                GestBDD.suppRDV(rdv,getContext());
                adapter.remove(getPosition(rdv));
                cl.notifyDataSetChanged();
                Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Rendez vous 
                supprimé",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
        builder.show();

        }
        }
```

the error is at builder.show() line and it says

```
     W/System.err:     at 
     com.example.hp.bendaoudtest.RDVAdapter.onClick(RDVAdapter.java:110)
```

Comment: remove this `builder.show();`  and add this `AlertDialog alert11 = builder.create();
alert11.show();`

Comment: @HemantParmar thanks for your reply, but your solution didn't work

Comment: can you share all stacktrace, it might be another issue.

Comment: @MikeM the class ActivityRDV is doing the listview manipulation, but the original (class and activity) that uses the adapter is ActivityListRDV

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AlertDialog only accepts **activity context** instead of **application context**. If your `getContext()` gets **application context** you are going to get an error. Your `getContext()` method should return **activity context** which can be instantiated from activity class you are using by sending `this` as constructor parameter. Don't send `getApplicationContext()` as constructor parameter. Example:

```
RVDAdapter rvdadapter = new RVDAdapter(this);
```

Comment: thank you, i worked for me i was using "getBaseContext()" in the Activity class, i changed it by this  RDVAdapter rdvadap = new RDVAdapter (this,R.layout.row,list);

Answer (score 1):

use

```
 AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
```

and

```
AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
dialog.show();
```

instead of `builder.show();` for more info 
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html

Comment: try to use getActivity() instead of getContext()